# Set fee in Electrum RPC

Tags: transaction-fees, json-rpc, electrum

I'd like to pay people using the following command:

```
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"payto","params":{"destination":"mwLmd5xMnKkf4bBUa6MDrg4HYQaazoHtkj", "amount":"0.001"}}'
```

But I don't know what will be charged as fee. Is it possible to set the fee?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are on testnet... INPUTS minus OUTPUTS = TX FEE.
So better to create a return adress. If there is only one UTXO in your wallet, and it has let's say 0.005 in it, by your line it would give 0.004 to the miners. So better to add a return address. You would have to add an address of your wallet. 
I haven't worked out the params field, but there should be an option to add a second param for output address?